# How to make jQuery Slider as a Lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I checked this plugin in this website [jquery slider as a Lightbox](http://www.menucool.com/slider/jquery-slider-lightbox) with this jQuery Slider as a Lightbox design and I would like to create one a similar without a plugin. Does anyone know where I can find a documentation or tutorial? Thanks

Comment: `Does anyone know where I can find a documentation or tutorial?` --> in the internet i guess, using google

Comment: Hi Temani, what I mean, and find tips, some documentation to get started.

Comment: i know what you meant and i answered :) everything is in the net, you simply need to search for it unless you want us to do it for you .. by the way the question is off-topic  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best slider's online is [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

You can set it to be a verticle slider via the option "vertical: true"
It's very customizable with your own css, and to achieve the slider in a lightbox effect you can wrap it in some html which displays on click with position fixed and a background with alpha.

```js
$('.slick').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  vertical: true
});

$('.button').on('click', (e) => {
   $('.modal').addClass('open');
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  background: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal.open {
  display: block;
}

.slick {
  margin: 0 auto;  
  max-width: 500px;
}

.slick-list {
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Open</button>
  
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="slick">
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi webbist, thank you so much for the support